# How can I get old copy of NEC?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

How can I get an older version of the NEC (National Electrical Code) online for free? Specifically, I need a copy of the “1975 NEC”. I could get it on Amazon for $29, but I’d rather not pay that much for it if I don’t have to. Or I could get the “Guide to the 1975 Electrical Code” for $9 (which I probably will get). I already checked to see if I could check out the physical book at my library. But it is not available. I also tried to find where it is published online so that I can just simply print out the pages that I need. But no luck.

Comment: "NEC for free" good luck doing that legally.

Comment: local libraries often have a copy you can use if not check out. often, they have older copies, but i don't know about THAT old. you might try the card catalog at the library, looking around other branches for an older publication date copy they will transfer in to you.

Comment: Aside from the well-stocked library reference section, Used bookshops, or for "only a few pages" sometimes googling the article number and 1975 NEC might get what you need. It's a bit surprising to find anywhere that far behind the times, though, so consider the potential improvements in safety as well as easier access to newer code years...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can purchase a used copy of the 1975 NEC starting at $7.18 at Amazon:

[1975 NEC at Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HWK0YM)

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the [NFPA website](http://www.nfpa.org/codes-and-standards/all-codes-and-standards/list-of-codes-and-standards/detail?code=70), you can you can get free access to read-only copies of the NEC.  You will have to sign up for an account though.

Looks like they have 1971 and 1978 versions available.